# Replace string with some condition in PHP

Tags: php

I have this string

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=13;BYDAY=MO,SU
```

Now the part **BYDAY=MO,SU** can be in any position like

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE,TH;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=5; -> BYDAY=WE
```

I just want to replace the value of **BYDAY=value**

let's say I have updated value of **BYDAY=FR**

I've tried to use **str_replace()** but the given value of of BYDAY can be anything like MO,TU,WE,TH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `preg_replace`, we can try:

```
$input = "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=13;BYDAY=MO,SU";
$output = preg_replace("/\bBYDAY=[^;]+/", "BYDAY=FR", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=13;BYDAY=MO,SU
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=13;BYDAY=FR
```

Comment: Let me test this out one moment

Comment: Oh wait. almost there. I wanted it only to have BYDAY=FR. Not BYDAY=FR,SU

Comment: Check the updated answer.  Didn't know you want to replace the entire CSV list of days.

Comment: Your sample data does not suggest this, so neither does my answer `:-)` ... please don't change your question at this point.

Comment: Perfect got it now thank you very much for help!

Comment: @Mark To cover the case of multiple `RRULE`, use: `preg_replace("/\bBYDAY=.*?(?![^;])/", "BYDAY=FR", $input)`.

Comment: Got it and tested working. Thanks @Tim